# How can you delete a value and not a key in a dictionary

Tags: python

so I have to delete 32.32 from the key 'breakfast blend' in my dictionary
How can I remove a single value??

```
print(transaction_dic_11)
for k in list(transaction_dic_11):
    if transaction_dic_11[k] == 32.32:
        del transaction_dic_11[k]

Transaction_dic = {'Classic': [37.33, 46.75, 28.18, 33.35],
                   'breakfast blend':[32.32, 46.94, 26.91, 22.03], 
                   'rev it up': [45.82, 33.89]}`
```

I tried this code, but it won't delete the value and no changes occur.

Comment: Maybe a job for `filter()`?

Comment: Be careful when comparing floating point values and expecting exact matches. If these are computed you may need to add a tiny +/- factor.

Comment: You seem to be asking how to delete something from a list. The list **is** the value

Comment: Don't think of this as 'a dictionary with multiple values per key', think of it as 'a dictionary with list()s as the values. Anything you can do to a list you can do to the dictionary. `Transaction_dic['breakfast blend'].remove(32.32)`

Answer (score 1):

## `transaction_dic_11[k] == 32.32` is ALWAYS false

Because `transaction_dic_11[k]` value is a list, not a int.

```py
for k in list(transaction_dic_11):
    print(transaction_dic_11[k])
    # [37.33, 46.75, 28.18, 33.35]
    # [32.32, 46.94, 26.91, 22.03]
    # [45.82, 33.89]
    # You can see that you have lists, not an int
    if transaction_dic_11[k] == 32.32:
        del transaction_dic_11[k]
```

## Use in operator and `.remove()`

You need to detect if the value is IN the list, and remove it if necessary.

LBYL approach:

```py
    if 32.32 in transaction_dic_11['breakfast blend']:
        transaction_dic_11['breakfast blend'].remove(32.32)
```

EAFP approach:

```py
    try:
        transaction_dic_11['breakfast blend'].remove(32.32)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

[LBYL vs EAFP: Preventing or Handling Errors in Python](https://realpython.com/python-lbyl-vs-eafp/)

Comment: great answer, but it would be even better if you explained the approach acronyms.

Comment: OP only wants to remove the value from the list associated with 'breakfast blend'

Comment: @JonSG I added a link, thanks for the request

Comment: @Pingu Good point, I updated the code snippets to better fit the OP question

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can simply do this:

```
Transaction_dic['breakfast blend'].remove(32.32)
```

However, floating point numbers are not always what they seem. You may have to look for values that are "close" to the value using some mechanism of tolerance you will need to devise.

Here's an example of how you might approach this:

```
def remove_if_near(_list, n, tolerance=0.000001):
    for i, x in enumerate(_list):
        if abs(x - n) < tolerance:
            _list.pop(i)
            break
    return _list

my_list = [1/3, 1/5, 1/9]
print(my_list)
print(remove_if_near(my_list, 0.333333))
```

**Output:**

```
[0.3333333333333333, 0.2, 0.1111111111111111]
[0.2, 0.1111111111111111]
```

**Note:**

If the list is sorted then this can be made more efficient. If not sorted then this will potentially be very inefficient for large lists